# Ruby: rake:22: undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I had this problems in Ruby 1.8.7-p374.

When try to run "rake db:migrate" i got this error:

```
RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /home/wellington/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/gem

RubyGems system software updated
/home/wellington/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/rake:22: undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Its occurs on deploy Rails apps.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this updating gem and bundler

```
gem update --system
gem update bundler
```