# rails 2.3.0 - undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to bundle install, rake db:migrate

```
bundle install

/home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I tried `gem install bundler`
it gives error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

which ruby

```
/home/smk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
```

rvm list

```
ruby-2.0.0-p648 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.5 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

I tried many solutions but no use
please any one help me.

Comment: do you have something in '~/.gemrc'? have you tried just reinstalling from scratch? 'rvm implode' and 'gem uninstall rvm'

Comment: path of /.gemrc? i tried whereis  /.gemrc, but it shows so many paths @robertoplancarte

Comment: the one in your home (/home/$USER/.gemrc), if the file doesn't exist then that is not the problem. Do any of the other rubies work? have you tried running rvm implode and gem uninstall rvm? That will remove rvm and you can install it from scratch again.

Comment: yes, reinstalled rvm, but same issue @robertoplancarte

Comment: Just run `gem install bundler` worked for me

Comment: OP wrote it tried `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39951874/5353461) suggests updatig `gem` and `bundler` thus:

```
gem update --system
gem update bundler
```

If that doesn't work, try renaming your `gems` directory, obtained by running `bundle show bundle`.